# startActivity calls first which is called after startActivityForResult call

Tags: android, android-activity

This is my first strange result that I never expected. This is may be lack of skill in that area.

Well I had a button, through which I need to select an image from the phone gallery (probably  from sdcard). I used implicit intent to call the phone gallery and got the absolute image path with `startActivityForResult()`. Immediately am calling another activity putting that path with `startActivity()`.

According to my scenario I wrote the following code in the `onClick()` of button.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        upLoadPhoto();
}

protected void upLoadPhoto() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    System.out.println("select image");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    startActivity(next);
    finish();
}

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 1 && data != null && data.getData() != null){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                if (uri != null) {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    System.out.println("Background : "+imageFilePath);
                    next.putExtra("backImagePath", imageFilePath);
                    cursor.close();
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button, `startActivity(next)` is called first, then `startActivityForResult(intent,1)` is called. As am trying to get image path in the second activity through bundle object, am getting `NullPointerException` because of `startActivity(next)` is being called first.

I dropped my jaws when I saw my debugging point are not as expected. Hope I get exact reason to this issue.

Thanks
Aswin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about moving the call to `startActivity(next);` into `onActivityResult()`... this way you will navigate to the other activity after getting the path

```
protected void upLoadPhoto() {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
System.out.println("select image");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

finish();
```

}

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                System.out.println("Background : "+imageFilePath);
                next.putExtra("backImagePath", imageFilePath);
                cursor.close();

            startActivity(next);

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you dear Nunu. But I deserve the reason for the issue. Could you please explain?

Comment: The problem is that calling activity for result takes some time, and when calling start activity right after startActivityForResult the system had to go to the next activity before finish processing onActivityResult (like openning 2 threads one is shorter than the other)

Comment: Thank you Nunu for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have call `startActivity()` inside `onActivityResult()` when your image is selected from Gallery successful. Because when `startActivityForResult()` it is going to Gallery for picking up the image and till then `startActivity()` is fired and you move to next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

remove that `startActivity(next)` from that function and put it on `onActivityResult` after you retrieve your data

Answer (score 0):

remove that startActivity(next) from that function  and put it on onActivityResult after get 1   add Your Next Intent